# Slight delay when switching modes in vim using tmux or screen

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, tmux

Switching to and from insert mode in Vim is no longer instantaneous since I use tmux. After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode, it takes a noticeable amount of time to actually get out of insert mode. After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and any other key afterwards the switch is immediate, and the command for the key pressed after <kbd>Esc</kbd> is executed. Any idea what might cause this?

The Vim configuration is not the problem as the delay does not occur when I run Vim outside tmux, so this is probably related to tmux somehow. I use gnome-terminal btw.

Also worth noting, it seems I can not define key bindings in tmux for <kbd>Esc</kbd>, my plan was to bind <kbd>Esc</kbd> to:

```
bind Escape send-keys ^[
```

Alas, it seems binding anything to <kbd>Esc</kbd> for tmux does not work. The same problem occurs in screen as well.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

After plowing through the man pages it turns out tmux has an option for this. The following in `~/.tmux.conf` fixes the delay problem:

```
 set -sg escape-time 5
```

You have to restart your tmux server or reload your config for this to take effect. To do this, issue `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` from the tmux prompt.

As pointed out by @Jonathan Wheeler (https://superuser.com/a/1809494), setting an escape time of zero is a bad idea but rather, set it to a low enough value such that you are not bothered by the delay.

Comment: Where did you find this? I can't find escape-time anywhere in `man tmux`, and the command doesn't work for me.

Comment: I suspect is is only available in the development version. You can get it here: https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux

Comment: I love everything about you for this answer. This just solved an obscure emacs problem for me and now I can go to bed finally!

Comment: I had to use tmux kill-server before this setting worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This makes me wish I could give you 10 upvotes. Found this after an hour of battling timeouts in vim. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I even killed the server and restarted, but the delay in vim is still there. I'm using tmux 1.9-6 (in debian testing).

Comment: It might be vim's own timeoutlen option. Reducing that from the default 1000 to 100 improved things a lot.

Comment: @MarkZar, which version of tmux are you using?

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel It worked after I rebooted my PC, I don't know why it needs a restart, but any way it works. Now working with vim in tmux is like a joyful journey, thanks!

Comment: @Searene That is probably because you had the tmux daemon running, it needs to be restarted for any settings changes to take effect.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel You changed my life!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: thanks! I never realised this could be fixed and it was driving me crazy, this is fantastic!!

Comment: This setting works with the vim plugin airline (or other plugins), but at first may look like it hasn't worked.  I set this and killed the tmux server, and tested it.  airline still takes about half a second to update the screen from showing `INSERT` to `NORMAL`, so I thought it wasn't working and went down a rabbit hole.  After actually trying commands during that split second where it still showed `INSERT`, I realized this setting worked, and I was actually in command mode.

Comment: ... To fix the apparent delay from plugins I mentioned, consider in `vimrc` `set ttimeoutlen=0` or maybe `=10`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550100/exit-visual-mode-without-delay/15550436#15550436

Comment: Funny, I never encountered this problem because I don't use esc in vim, I use ^[ always. It's a quicker movement than reaching for the esc key.

Comment: @MichaelBrown, I do as well, and still hit this problem. It should not matter actually, because the same key code is sent to the terminal emulator regardless of whether you press escape or ^[.

Comment: After spending many days ripping my hair out over an aggravating issue, I would highly recommend *NOT* setting escape-time to 0, but rather **changing it to a low value of something like 50** (from the default of 500). Why? Per https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/2060#issuecomment-1146634027 "escape-time 0 prevents tmux from recognizing escape sequences that are fragmented across read/packet boundaries. Raise that to a more reasonable value such as 100ms which should be enough time for most cases while still being quick enough that it shouldn't cause human-scale interaction issues."

Answer (score 9):

I had a different but similar issue that I was trying to solve when I found this page, so I'll post that here in case it's helpful to anyone else who is in search of this answer and finds this page in the same way.

**Problem: vi mode in bash has a delay when switching from insert mode to command mode**

**Solution:** In your `~/.inputrc` file, add `set keyseq-timeout n` where `n` is some low value greater than 0.  `n` defaults to 500ms, which is what causes the delay.  See documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html).

Also, if you want to be able to tell which mode you're in, check out [Dylan Cali's fork of bash](https://github.com/calid/bash).

Comment: that is very helpful, i set it to `0.01` and now its pleasingly much more faster. thanks!

Comment: It could also be appended  into `/etc/inputrc` to make it available for all users.

Comment: zsh has an additional delay setting: `KEYTIMEOUT` -- https://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR:

**DO NOT** use `escape-time 0`, but rather set it to a *low* value.

In `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -s escape-time 50  # ~5-100. https://superuser.com/a/1809494/224906
```

Finish by either reloading your tmux config or restarting your tmux server. (In your CLI, run either `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` or `tmux kill-server; tmux`.)

#### Detailed Explanation:

After spending several days over the last couple of months tracking down a very annoying (non-deterministic and seemingly random) issue while remotely connected to a tmux server (via iTerm2 3.4.20 -> zsh 5.8.1 -> ssh 8.9p1 -> zsh 5.8.1 -> tmux 3.3a), I would highly recommend *NOT* setting escape-time to 0 (as suggested by others here, and even by [tmux-sensible](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible), which links to this very question at the time of my post), but rather **setting escape-time to a *lower* value of something like 10 or 50** (from the default of 500).

Why? I finally discovered the solution in the GitHub issue ["tmux 3.3 leaks text into shell"](https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/2060#issuecomment-1146634027):

> `escape-time 0` prevents tmux from recognizing escape sequences that are fragmented across read/packet boundaries. You should raise that to a more reasonable value such as 100ms which should be enough time for most cases while still being quick enough that it shouldn't cause human-scale interaction issues.

He is using a completely different terminal than me (wezterm vs iTerm2), yet is experiencing a very similar issue of a combined CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) and DCS (Device Control String) escape sequence—specifically `\033[>0;95;0c\033P>|iTerm2 3.4.20\033\\`—leaking into the shell in response to the CSI escape sequences `CSI > c` (aka `\033 [ > c`) and `CSI > q` (aka `\033 [ > q`). (Which, at least for me, seem to always occur in sequence immediately after one another.)

After some time, this would cause a random paste to occur in my vim buffer, followed by     `Term2 3.4.20` [sic] being prepended to the pasted text.

#### Further detail to help others searching for this solution:

The combined CSI and DCS sequence `\033[>0;95;0c\033P>|iTerm2 3.4.20\033\\` causes the following in vim: `\033[>0;95;0c\033` doesn't do much, `P` pastes whatever is in vim's unnamed/default register, `>|` tabs the line to the right, `i` enters insert mode, `Term2 3.4.20` is inserted into the buffer, `\033` escapes back out of insert mode, and the final `\\` basically does nothing.

I've observed that this happens more often when I'm on the road, and especially when using an unreliable and slow mobile connection. This now makes perfect sense, since packet latency is greater under these conditions, and since I was using a `escape-time 0`.

**TL;DR: Don't use `escape-time 0`; it exists for a good reason.** Give it a low reasonable value (like 5, 50, or 100) that will still work well when connected remotely. Adjust as needed to find the right balance. If the value is too high, it'll interfere with human-scale interactions. If the value is too low, you may experience escape sequence artifacts and bugs.

Edit: This problem and solution is also cited in [this Microsoft WSL issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5931), which similarly links back to this question.

Edit #2: I've also learned that the issues I described above can (and perhaps more likely) be due to [`TTY_QUERY_TIMEOUT` in `tmux/tty.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/b77778072052c14d1450d2eb89542f2493121f84/tty.c#L89) not being set [high enough](https://groups.google.com/g/tmux-users/c/PgHOmk6oInA), but this is beyond the scope of this question. It remains true that you shouldn't use `escape-time 0` for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

As the title mentions Screen, here is the solution to fix the behaviour of Escape key within GNU Screen. (Taken from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration).)

Add

```
maptimeout 5
```

to `.screenrc` config file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a mapping that starts with <kbd>ESC</kbd>.  When you press the <kbd>ESC</kbd>, vim has to wait to see if the next key is the one in the mapping.  If it is not, it can immediately continue.

The vim configuration can be terminal dependent, so the fact that it does not happen outside of tmux does not mean much.  Vim can query the `$TERM` environment variable and choose different configuration depending on its value.

Since gnome-terminal uses, AFAIK, `xterm` as the value of the `$TERM` variable, and tmux uses `screen`,  I would look through all your vim configuration files for settings that are only used is the `$TERM` variable is equal to `screen`.  My guess is that some vim config file on your system sets mappings for handling of arrow keys (those start with the `ESC` character) when the terminal is `screen`.

You can test it by temporarily changing the `$TERM` variable in tmux before starting vim.  If your shell is bash, call vim as

```
TERM=xterm vim
```

in tmux and see if the problem persists.  You sould not use that as a fix, though, since there may be differences between the terminal capabilities of tmux and xterm, and you may run into some problems.

Comment: Some good pointers here. I do use bash, but unfortunately `TERM=xterm vim` did not fix the problem. I'll have to dig a little deeper.