# Why is the -s or -g option required while setting escape-time option in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am unable to understand why exactly the `-s` or `-g` option is
required while setting the `escape-time` option in tmux. Here are some
answers that seem to use the `-s` or `-g` option while setting
`escape-time`:

- https://superuser.com/a/252717/115290
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25638

Here are some experiments:

```
tmux kill-server
tmux
tmux detach
tmux

# Now we have two tmux sessions named [0] and [1] with [1] being the
# current session.

tmux set escape-time 2000
vim

# Press 'i' to get into insert mode.
# Then press 'Escape' to return to command mode. It takes 2 seconds.
# Enter ':q' to quit Vim.

tmux switch-client -t 0
vim

# Press 'i' to get into insert mode.
# Then press 'Escape' to return to command mode. It takes 2 seconds.
# Enter ':q' to quit Vim.
```

The conclusion of the above experiment is that `escape-time` option set
in one session affects all sessions automatically.

Why is the `-s` or `-g` option required then?